# Python Mercury offline installation

Tags: python

I need to install `mercury` package to local machine with Windows. I downloaded with `pip download mercury` on a machine with internet and moved into the first directory.

I tried:

```
pip install mercury --no-index --find-links=./mercury
```

but got errors:

[image]

There isn't a .whl file for mercury inside folder, how to install it offline?

Comment: It's a dependency issue. Download and install `wheel`.

Comment: @s3dev I extracted, but didn't find .whl files

Comment: python version 3.11.5

Comment: @s3dev i installed `wheel` but it doesn't help

Comment: Ok. Please try the suggestions in the answer. If error persist, please *update the question* as 'Edit: ...' and post the new errors.  There might be more than one issue, we'll peel them off in turn.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two questions here:

1. What is the cause of the error?
2. Why don't I see any `.whl` files in the `mercury` directory?

---

> What is the cause of the error?

As stated in the error message:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
```

**Fix:** This is a dependency issue. Download and install `wheel`

Alternatively, you can just 'manually' download the `wheel` wheel from their [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/#files), and transfer across to the offline environment.

---

> Why don't I see any `.whl` files in the mercury directory?

This is OK. It simply means that the authors have not compiled the `mercury` source code into a binary wheel. If you look at the [PyPI page for mercury](https://pypi.org/project/mercury/#files) you'll only see the `tar.gz` file listed - there are no wheels.

The `tar.gz` is an archive (e.g. zip file) created with `tar` and compressed with `gzip`. This archive contains the *source code* for the library. This is OK because `pip` is 'clever enough' to spot this and install `mercury` from source, and compile where necessary.

```
cd mercury
pip install mercury-2.3.8.tar.gz -f . --no-index
```

Comment: Thank you! I moved weel.whl to directory mercury and run you code. It works!

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working for you.  Happy to help.